# Ramanujan's $\pi(x)^{2}<{\frac {ex}{\log x}}\pi {\bigg (}{\frac {x}{e}}{\bigg )}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Counting_Function#Inequalities

"In his well-known notebooks, Ramanujan[23] proves that the inequality

$$\pi(x)^{2}<{\frac {ex}{\log x}}\pi {\bigg (}{\frac {x}{e}}{\bigg )}$$

holds for all sufficiently large values of $x$."

It is the "holds for all sufficiently large values of $x$" part that I need some help. I do not have the book to verify the proof (Is is correct?), and I wonder if someone has computed the minimum value of x?

Comment: I just found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577007/ramanujans-prime-counting-inequality

Comment: The link there is to a paper which has the min holding value of x. But I can not see the whole paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed by Axler in [arXiv:1703.02407](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02407); see Theorems 1.3, 1.4 and surrounding discussion. In particular, if the Riemann hypothesis is true, then
$$
\pi(x)^{2}<{\frac {ex}{\log x}}\pi {\bigg (}{\frac {x}{e}}{\bigg )}
\qquad\mbox{ for all }x\ge 38 358 837 683.
$$
Regardless of the Riemann hypothesis, Axler proves that
$$
\pi(x)^{2}<{\frac {ex}{\log x}}\pi {\bigg (}{\frac {x}{e}}{\bigg )}
\qquad\mbox{ for all }x\ge e^{9032}.
$$
The largest known integer $x$ for which the inequality fails is
$$
x=38 358 837 682;
$$
we have
$$
\pi(x)^2=2704950040057325824, \qquad
{\frac {ex}{\log x}}\pi {\bigg (}{\frac {x}{e}}{\bigg )}=
2704950040042588896.1001\ldots
$$